# how does gets() work inside a loop in C?

Tags: c, gets

I had the following loop in my  C program:

```
while (t != 0) {
    scanf("%s", &u);
    intopost(u, v);
    printf("%s\n", v);
    t--;
}
```

If I use `gets()` function instead of `scanf()` inside the loop ,the loop runs one less than the actual value of `t`. Can anyone explain why is this happening?
following is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct stack {
    int data[400];
    int top;
} stack;
void init(stack* s) { s->top = -1; }
int empty(stack* s) {
    if (s->top == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int full(stack* s) {
    if (s->top == 399)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void push(stack* s, char c) {
    s->top++;
    s->data[s->top] = c;
}
char pop(stack* s) {
    char x = s->data[s->top];
    s->top--;
    return x;
}
void intopost(char in[], char po[]) {
    stack s;
    char c, x;
    int i, j = 0;
    init(&s);
    for (i = 0; in [i] != '\0'; i++) {
        x = in[i];
        if (isalnum(x))
            po[j++] = x;
        else {
            if (x == ')') {
                if (!empty(&s))
                    po[j++] = pop(&s);
            } else if (x != '(') {
                if (!full(&s))
                    push(&s, x);
            }
        }
    }
    po[j] = '\0';
}
int main() {
    int t;
    char u[400], v[400];
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (t != 0) {
        scanf("%s", &u);
        intopost(u, v);
        printf("%s\n", v);
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()` it is obsolete and what is the value of `t`?

Comment: t is value given by user

Comment: I want to know why its running on one time less?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...) then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Preferably give some self-contained program source code on StackOverflow.

Comment: @user2563312 Problems you post on SO should be reproducible and code should be compilable.

Answer (score 3):

The first `scanf` reads the number, but leaves the newline in the input buffer.
`scanf` inside the loop skips the newline that is left after you `scanf` the number, but `gets` doesn't.

So, with input:

```
3
a
b
c
```

With `gets` you get the following 3 lines:

```
   -- the newline after the 3
a
b
```